# Microsoft Graph API message edit and move requests returning BrokenPipeError for specific tenant

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We encountered a large amount of "Connection aborted. BrokenPipeError" responses from a specific tenant. We are using the (email) message edit and move APIs. These errors seem to be happening more frequently in certain hours. The error itself does not contain any additional information and we weren't able to find in depth documentation. Any recommendations on how to investigate and resolve these issues?

Comment: While you are experiencing this issue does it does it happen for any other operation to Graph other than message edit move requests? This seems like a connection issue. You could post the raw logs without private info. Also note that if the issue happens only for a specific tenant the you should create a support request to get help.